# SSRS - how to evaluate totals per month

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services

I have to create a report that has a field called "Payment Status".  In essence this field is based on how a customer has paid for the last 4 months.  Eg if he/she has paid monthly, then this field evaluates as "Recurring".  If he/she has paid in months 1, 2, 3 but not in month 4, then the answer is "Fall Off" and so on.

I have all the payments data as follows:

```
Customer ID  | Month_Yr  |  Pymnt_Dt    |  Pymnt_Amnt
34566          Mar15     | 12 Mar 2015  |  1260
34566          Mar15     | 19 Mar 2015  |  1450
34566          Apr15     | 12 Apr 2015  |  1300
34566          May15     | 12 May 2015  |  1200
34566          May15     | 19 May 2015  |  145
34566          Jun15     | 08 June 2015 |  150
34566          Jun15     | 25 June 2015 |  1900
34567          May15     | 03 May 2015  |  2560
34567          May15     | 16 May 2015  |  1500
34567          May15     | 22 May 2015  |  190
34567          Jun15     | 02 June 2015 |  1456
34567          Jun15     | 20 June 2015 |  1300
```

How can I figure out what status to enter?  I can group by customer ID and Month_Yr and get totals per Month_Yr for each customer.  But on the customer grouping, how do I determine the Status?

Comment: You have multiple payments per month per customer, paying once 150 is enough to count as a valid payment?

Comment: Yes, any payment means that that entire month's status would be 'paid'.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't very "clean" but should return something you can work with.

```
DECLARE @Months_to_Fall_Off INT = 4;

SELECT
    Customer_ID,
    case [Payment Status]
        when @Months_to_Fall_Off then 'Recurring'
        else 'Fall Off'
    end [Payment Status]
FROM (
    select
        Customer_ID,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
            PARTITION BY
                Customer_ID
            ORDER BY
                Pymnt_Dt DESC
        ) [Payment Status],
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
            PARTITION BY
                Customer_ID
            ORDER BY
                Pymnt_Dt
        ) lastPay
    from (
        SELECT
            Customer_ID,
            Month_Yr,
            MAX(Pymnt_Dt)Pymnt_Dt,
            SUM(Pymnt_Amnt)Pymnt_Amnt
        FROM Pymnt_table p
        WHERE
            Pymnt_Dt >= DATEADD(MONTH,-@Months_to_Fall_Off,GETDATE())
        GROUP BY
            Customer_ID,
            Month_Yr
    ) t
) t
where
    lastPay = 1
```